# Replace string values in pandas to their count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I`m trying to calculate count of some values in data frame like

```
user_id  event_type
    1         a   
    1         a  
    1         b
    2         a
    2         b
    2         c
```

and I want to get table like

```
user_id  event_type  event_type_count  
    1         a           2              
    1         a           2              
    1         b           1              
    2         a           1              
    2         b           1              
    2         c           2
    2         c           2
```

In other words, I want to insert count of value instead value in data frame.
I've tried use `df.join(pd.crosstab)...`, but I get a large data frame with many columns.

Which way is better to solve this problem ?

Comment: Why in the last row user_id 2 and event_type c get 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by both columns with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['event_type_count'] = df.groupby(['user_id','event_type'])['event_type'].transform('size')
print (df)
   user_id event_type  event_type_count
0        1          a                 2
1        1          a                 2
2        1          b                 1
3        2          a                 1
4        2          b                 1
5        2          c                 2
6        2          c                 2
```